# Update position of shadow camera in render loop

Tags: three.js, camera, shadow

I'm trying to set the position of my directional light shadow camera to be the same as my main perspective camera in the render loop:

```
sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
sunlight.position.x = camera.position.x ;
sunlight.position.y = 300;
sunlight.position.z = camera.position.z ;from top
sunlight.castShadow = true;

sunlight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048 ;
sunlight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048 ;
sunlight.shadow.bias = -0.0027;

sunlight.shadow.camera.left = -75;
sunlight.shadow.camera.right = 75;
sunlight.shadow.camera.top = 75;
sunlight.shadow.camera.bottom = -75;
sunlight.shadow.camera.position = camera.position;

sunlight.shadow.camera.far = sunlight.position.distanceTo(scene.position) + 20;
sunlight.shadow.camera.near = sunlight.position.distanceTo(scene.position) - (camera.position.y * 2);

sunlight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();


function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    sunlight.shadow.camera.position = camera.position;
    sunlight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

However the shadow camera does not move at all. Is it possible to update the position of a shadow camera during run-time?

Answer (score 0):

The shadow.camera is more of an internal component to the sunlight.

The way to move the sunlight so that it follows the camera is more something like this:

```
sunlight.position.copy( camera.position );
sunlight.target.copy( camera.position );
sunlight.position.y += 20;
```

this ^ should make the sunlight stay above the camera, pointing down, at a distance of 20 units.

Also your shadow.camera.near / far setup looks a little weird.

I would just set those to something like

```
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
light.shadow.camera.far = 50.0;
```

..or something like that.